# Google auth not working on production , but working perfectly on localhost

Tags: reactjs, node.js, oauth-2.0, passport.js

Implemented Google auth strategy using passport.js on Node.js . It works perfectly fine on localhost
but when I try on deployment it keeps on giving me URL_MISMATCH . even when i have correctly put the
URL in google cloud console api credentials.

It sends the correct call on my backend server url , the only change is , it sends on http ,  not on https.why?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.